# How search triple elements (key_value pair Dictionary) by one of them

Tags: c#, dictionary

Here is my code:

```
public class PairedKeys
{
    public byte Key_1 { get; set; }
    public byte Key_2 { get; set; }

    public PairedKeys(byte key_1, byte key_2)
    {
        Key_1 = key_1;
        Key_2 = key_2;
    }
}

public static class My_Class
{
    static Dictionary<PairedKeys, char> CharactersMapper = new Dictionary<PairedKeys, char>()
    {
        { new PairedKeys(128, 48), 'a' },
        { new PairedKeys(129, 49), 'b' }
    }
}
```

How can I get value of `CharactersMapper` by searching `Key_2`?

Here's my attempt:

```
for (int j = 0; j < CharactersMapper.Count; j++)
{
    try
    {
        char ch = CharactersMapper[new PairedKeys(????, Key_2)];
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using LINQ, you can do the following to return a single item:

```
var ch = CharactersMapper.Single(cm => cm.Key.Key_2 == 49);
```

Or if you're expecting more than one item:

```
var chList = CharactersMapper.Where(cm => cm.Key.Key_2 == 49);
```

These will return a `KeyValuePair<‌​Classes.PairedKeys,char>` and `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<‌​Classes.PairedKeys,char>>` as you've noted in the comments.  If you want to get at just the `char` contents, you can use the `Select` method:

```
//Single char
char singleChar = CharactersMapper.Single(cm => cm.Key.Key_2 == 49).Select(c => c.Value);

//list of chars
IList<char> charList = CharactersMapper.Where(cm => cm.Key.Key_2 == 49).Select(c => c.Value).ToList();
```

Comment: here in the error :  Error 4 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<Classes.PairedKeys,char>>' to 'char'

Comment: also i tried this :  ch_ar[i] = char.Parse(CharactersMapper.Where(cm => cm.Key.Arabic_Byte == charByte)); -> that error still exists...

Comment: @MoonLight Yes the above will return a `KeyValuePair<‌​Classes.PairedKeys,char>`.  I'll update the answer to include how to get at just the `char`s

Answer (score 2):

Using dictionary in this manner, there's not going to be an optimized (i.e. `O(1)`) way of achieving this. You can, however, just loop through, which will be `O(n)`:

```
var result = dictionary.Where(d => d.Key.Key_2 == 3);
```

assuming you're looking for `3`, of course.

Comment: P.s. `Key_2` isn't a nice C#py name for a property - I'd go for simply `Key2`.

Comment: @MoonLight Also I think you'll want to make `PairedKey`s a struct and override `GetHashCode` and `Equals` for best performance when you're using the normal `dictionary[key]` syntax.